# Differential Equation Confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x + 2y + 1}{2x+4y - 1}$.

I substitute for $v = x + 2y$ and end up getting $ 0 = x+2y + 3/2 \log(2x+4y - 1) +C$ which is not an answer choice (there is an answer choice that marks non-of-the-above, but i think I made a mistake). Ideas anyone?

Comment: What are the choices? I posted an answer, but the choice could be multiples of the implicit form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following substitution:

$$
z=y-x/2$$
Then
$$
\frac{dz}{dx}= \frac{dy}{dx}-\frac12 = {{1}\over{2\,\left(4\,z+4\,x+1\right)}}$$

Next make the substitution:
$$
v=z+x$$
to get
$$
\frac{dv}{dx}= \frac{dz}{dx} + 1={{8\,v+3}\over{2\,\left(4\,v+1\right)}}$$
Hence
$${{8\,v+2}\over{8\,v+3}} dv = dx$$
or
$$\left(1-{{1}\over{8\,v+3}}\right) dv = dx$$
Integrating
$$-x-{{\log \left(8\,v+3\right)}\over{8}}+v=C$$
Now replace $v$ by $z+x$ and then $z$ by $y-x/2$ to get
$$-{{\log \left(8\,y+4\,x+3\right)-8\,y+4\,x}\over{8}}=C$$
Multiplying out the $8$:

$$-\log \left(8\,y+4\,x+3\right)+8\,y-4\,x=C$$

Comment: oh.. got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you have substituted $v=x+2y$ to give
$${\rm RHS}=\frac{v+1}{2v-1}$$
and then integrated the RHS with respect to $v$.  But the problem is a differential **equation**, it has a LHS as well as a RHS and you have to take that into account too.  To get the LHS in terms of the new variable $v$ instead of $y$ you have to differentiate:
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=1+2\frac{dy}{dx}\ ,$$
and so the rewritten DE is
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=1+2\Bigl(\frac{v+1}{2v-1}\Bigr)\ .$$
This is now a DE of a standard form which I am sure you have studied in your course.  See how you go.